# How is your support for older 64 bit AMD processors?

Tags: amd, cpu

I have an older PC with 2 core AMD 64 bit processors. Your specs seem to call for an Intel i3 processor as the minimum.

Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of subjective but actually there is no problem at all running elementary OS 0.4 loki on 2 core AMD 64 bit if you have enough RAM (4-8 GB)

Comment: I agree. I recently put Elementary on my old single core AMD Athlon and it is amazingly scootin'. John shouldn't have an issue, just use programs that meet your hardware specifications after Elementary is installed.

Answer (score -1):

I made a bootable usb of 64-bit Loki and it only showed a blinking cursor on my 64-but compatible AMD A4-3300 desktop. Same usb worked on my newer i7 laptop. I heard that ubuntu 16.04 had a change in amd drivers (https://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx) I don't know how to force it to use the new open source drivers as this is a live usb which cannot even boot up.

Note: i tried turning off integrated graphics (it has integrated radeon) but it caused the computer to not display anything, even the bios.

Comment: Graphics support is decidedly tricky, but I'm not sure this actually shows a lack of support for _AMD processors_.